# Using SQL LIKE with variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-like

I can't use the SQL `LIKE` with a variable

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE name LIKE 'Motherboard' "; //This works
```

But if a use a variable it doesn't work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE name LIKE '%'+$variable+'%' ";
//or
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE name LIKE '$variable' ";
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: `+` is not the way to concatenate strings use `.` Besides you should escape your input variables.

Comment: All that looks fine, it doesn't appear the error exist in the code you have provided us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you concatenate strings with a dot .

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE name LIKE '" . $variable . "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use variables within double quotes:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE name LIKE '$variable' ";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE name LIKE '{$variable}' ";
```

Keep in mind that double quotes work slower then single.
In your case it would be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE name LIKE '%{$variable}%' ";
```